# Backend data filtering. EF with mapping to DTO

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, automapper

I'm using EF core with automapper and I need to do data filtering, that depends on frontend.

My question is what will be the right sequence:

1. Get entries -> do filtering -> convert to DTO

```
var query = dbContext.Tasks
      .AsNoTracking();

    if (paginationMeta.From != null)
    {
      query = query.Where(x => x.Date > paginationMeta.From);
    }

return query.ToList()
```

or

2. Get entries -> convert to DTO -> do filtering

```
var query = dbContext.Tasks
       .ProjectTo<DTO>()
      .AsNoTracking();

    if (paginationMeta.From != null)
    {
      query = query.Where(x => x.DateMapped > paginationMeta.From);
    }

return query.ToList()
```

Convert to DTO first seems more convenient way but in case of complicated mapping it leads to slower execution

How do you usually do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From AutoMapper’s [Queryable Extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) docs:

> `ProjectTo` must be the last call in the chain. ORMs work with entities, not DTOs. So apply any filtering and sorting on entities and, as the last step, project to DTOs.

So the correct one is the first (I even doubt that the second one will work, as far as I remember it should result in an exception).

Comment: The second works without throwing exception

Comment: @IngBond what version of runtime and EF Core. It's been quite some time since I've used the `ProjectTo` extensively so maybe my memory is letting down or maybe AutoMapper has changed something.

Comment: Most likely it's not about AM, it's about EF Core. EF Core is better than EF6 at working with DTOs. Regardless, entities will always work best.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu yes, that was at my mind too.